# How to use api edit phabricator repository URI

Tags: phabricator

I want to add repository URI and set it to observe mode, so I tried to change default URI I/O mode from `Read/Write` to `No IO`. I tried `diffusion.uri.edit`, in repository key description, it said:

> This transaction type must be present when creating a new URI and must
>   not be present when editing an existing URI.

I tested it with web `conduit/method/diffusion.uri.edit`. In transactions, I use

```
[
    {"type": "uri","value": "ssh://git@05.mm.net/diffusion/TESTPROCESS/test-process.git"},
    {"type": "io","value": "none"}
]
```

It report Validation errors:

> When creating a repository URI, you must specify which repository the
>   URI will belong to.

I also tried add repository key such as

```
[
    {"type": "uri","value": "ssh://git@git.missfresh.cn:test/test-process.git"},
    {"type": "io","value": "none"},
    {"type": "repository","value": "PHID-REPO-c7jajliasqtxoclryfim"}
]
```

It will create a new URI. What's the correct value for `diffusion.uri.edit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The transactions parameters are correct, but objectIdentifier is needed also, its value is the URI ID.